# Keras concatenate is not defined when loading the model

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

In one of my lambda layers, I used `from keras.layers import concatenate` to concatenate two tensors and it worked without any problem during training and I successfully saved the model files.

However, when I'm loading the model, it throws me this error:

> NameError: name 'concatenate' is not defined

Does anyone know what might be wrong? I've imported concatenate before I load the model.

The lambda layer looks like this:

```
def concat_l1_l2(vests):
    l1, l2 = vests
    l1 = K.l2_normalize(l1, axis=-1)
    l2 = K.l2_normalize(l2, axis=-1)
    return concatenate([l1, l2])
```

Comment: A likely problem is that one of your scripts is called `keras` or `keras.layers` - take a careful look at your naming first.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I don't have a script name like that..

Comment: The error comes from the function in model_from_json in keras.models

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue when loading a model from a json file, try the following line (it worked for me):

```
from keras.layers import concatenate
model_from_json(model_file, custom_objects={'concatenate': concatenate})
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following will solve your problem.
Try to pass your costum function to the load function of keras, i.e.

```
load(model_path,{"concat_l1_l2":concat_l1_l2})
```

Comment: Still the same error... The error comes from the function in model_from_json in keras.models

Comment: That's weird... Did you try saving and loading models as .h5-files?

Comment: Ya I did.. I tried both Concatenate, concatenate and save the model in two different ways (json&weights, entire model).. and they all gave me that error

Comment: Okay... Now this comes to random guessing... did you try to import it like that: import keras.layers.concatenate?